# How to change the fontfamily of equations in environment

Tags: fonts, equations, fontsize

When we change fontfamily in an environment, the equations font does not change.
It makes the whole environment is asynchronous.
[image]
Please show me how to change the family font of the equation in this environment.
Thank you in advance.
This is my MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
%\usepackage{cmbright} 
\newenvironment{note}{\par\noindent\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont}{}
\begin{document}
\noindent Normal text heigth equals to equations text $ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=z $.
 \begin{note}
Normal text heigth does not equal to equations text $ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=z $.
 \end{note}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `sansmath` package with `\fontfamily{qag}\mathversion{sans}` might  look better.

Comment: @Davislor. Thank you very much. Let me try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

With `mathastext` you may define a math font using `\MTDeclareVersion[it]{pag}{T1}{pag}{m}{n}`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.8cm]{geometry}

\newenvironment{note}{%
    \par\noindent\MTversion{pag}% changes both math font and text font as well
    }{}

    \usepackage[defaultmathsizes, subdued, italic, LGRgreek, symbolre, symbolmisc]{mathastext}
    \MTDeclareVersion[it]{pag}{T1}{pag}{m}{n} % declares a font version
    
\begin{document}
    
    \noindent Normal text height is equal to math text $ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=z$.
    
    \begin{note}
        Normal text height is equal to math text inside \verb|note| as well $ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=z$.
    \end{note}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @NamTranLe. At StackExchange. When an answer works for you, you should usually choose it as best answer by clicking the 'correct' sign. Choosing correct answer boosts your reputation by 2 points

Comment: Yes sir. The mathastext package is conflict with Vietnam package. When I use \usepackage[utf8]{vietnam},  It makes "issing number, treated as zero. \ifmst@eulergreek" error.

Comment: The Vietnamese package use T5 encode. Please help me correct this error.

Comment: If the mathastext package is put before the vietnam package, it work well.

Answer (score 0):

By Mr @Davislor's sugguestion, I edit the MWE.
The code is below, works well with Vietnam package.
Thank you for all helps!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage[margin=2.8cm]{geometry}
\newenvironment{note}{\par\noindent\usefont{T5}{cmbr}{m}{n}\begin{sansmath}\ignorespaces}{\end{sansmath}\ignorespacesafterend}
\begin{document}
\noindent Normal text heigth equals to equations text $ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=z $.
 \begin{note}
Nội dung tiếng Việt $ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=z$.
 \end{note}
\end{document}
```